# PHP цикл для элементов HTML

Tags: php, html, циклы

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой и никак в голову не приходит решение данной задачи.
У меня в карточке товара есть карусель, для просмотра нескольких фотографий из базы данных. Но иногда фотографий меньше. По стандарту в базе 3 поля: **image_prev1**, **image_prev2**, **image_prev3**.

Допустим, я добавил 2 фотографии в товар, а третья выходит пустой и так и выводится на сайте, как пустой белый блок. а мне нужно чтобы если это возможно прогонялась циклом и смотрело, есть ли фотография поля, если да то выводить.

Comment: Как вы в цикл эти данные заносите если они у вас просто отдельными полями? Покажите код где у вас сама карусель и что в этой переменной которую прогоняете циклом

Comment: <div class="wrap_swipebox clr">
     <div class="carousel-arrow-left"><span></span></div>
     <div class="carousel-hider">
      <ul class="carousel-list">
       <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev1?>" class="swipebox"></li>
       <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev2?>" class="swipebox"></li>
       <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev3?>" class="swipebox"></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-arrow-right"><span></span></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто проверять переменные на пустоту, и если переменная не пустая тогда добавлять её в карусель:

```
<?php

//Функцию желательно вынести куда нибудь подальше от HTML
function isValidCarouselImage($field) {
    if (empty($field)) {
        return false;
    }

    $array = explode('.', $field);
    $extension = end($array);
    $available_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    if (!in_array($extension, $available_extensions)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
?>

<ul class="carousel-list">
    <?php if (isValidCarouselImage($model_prev1)):?>
    <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev1?>" class="swipebox"></li> 
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if (isValidCarouselImage($model_prev2)):?>
    <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev2?>" class="swipebox"></li> 
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if (isValidCarouselImage($model_prev3)):?>
    <li class="carousel-element"><img src="<?=$model_prev3?>" class="swipebox"></li> 
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>
```

Но лучше бы хранить всё это в одной колонке в `json` думаю, если скажут завтра сделать 5 превью не надо будет добавлять ещё 2 колонки, ещё лишние строчки кода для слайдера, и проще будет выводить всё это.

UPD. Добавил функцию проверки, но лучше это делать в момент сохранения, а не уже вывода.

Comment: Оуу, спасибо! к этой же проверке можешь прикрутить проверку на расширение если оно в конце будет .jpg, .jpeg, .png

Comment: @CyberX обновил ответ

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо за помощь:) + поставил

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

Проверяйте на значение поля в таблице:

```
<?php
...
//допустим у вас есть значения картинок...
$query_result->image_prev1="img1";
$query_result->image_prev2="img2";
$query_result->image_prev3="img3";
...
if($query_result->image_prev1 !== "")
    //выводим картинку
if($query_result->image_prev2 !== "")
    //выводим картинку
if($query_result->image_prev3 !== "")
    //выводим картинку
...
//допустим у вас нет последней картинки и...
$query_result->image_prev1="img1";
$query_result->image_prev2="img2";
$query_result->image_prev3="";
...
if($query_result->image_prev3 !== "")
    //не выведет картинку

?>
```